# Jquery: Generic function to calculate input values in realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic form with multiple fields. I need to calculate the values entered in those fields in realtime using jquery.
I know we can simply do it by getting `$('#someID').val();` values but here I have multiple input fields which needs to be calculated.
These input fields are generated from a dynamic data. So need some kind of generic code which will suit any number of fields.

> Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sohal/xLLjoego/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **classes** instead of ID for **all** your fields

```
<input type="text" class="form-control emp_weekday_hrs" name="emp0[weekday_hrs]" id="emp0_weekday_hrs">
```

then in jQuery update the values for the **same row**

```
$('body').on('change', '.emp_weekday_hrs, .emp_weekend_hrs, .emp_cash_hrs', function(){
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var hrs1 = parseFloat($('.emp_weekday_hrs', $row).val()) || 0;
  var hrs2 = parseFloat($('.emp_weekend_hrs', $row).val()) || 0;
  var hrs3 = parseFloat($('.emp_cash_hrs', $row).val()) || 0;

  var rate1 = parseFloat($('.emp_weekday_rate', $row).val()) || 0;
  var rate2 = parseFloat($('.emp_weekend_rate', $row).val()) || 0;
  var rate3 = parseFloat($('.emp_cash_rate', $row).val()) || 0;

    var totalHrs = hrs1 + hrs2 + hrs3;
  var totalSalary = hrs1*rate1 + hrs2*rate2 + hrs3*rate3

    $('.emp_total_hrs', $row).val(totalHrs);
    $('.emp_total_salary', $row).val(totalSalary);
})
```

Example here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xLLjoego/9/)

Comment: please use event delegation technique as OP is asking for dynamically generated fields.

Comment: @vijayP woops, tnx

Comment: The final row of the fiddle doesn't respond to input

Comment: @SinanGuclu dude, i just didn't want to add classes to all the rows

Comment: @pumpkinzzz my bad

Answer (score 0):

My solution will work with your given `ids` by your html, there are no changes needed on this. But still a better way would be to change them to `classes` for better identification in the event listener, but this will work too.

The script will select the `input` ids inside the parent `tr` and calulate the row amounts. Note that I've change the listener to a live delegation on the `table` and added `keyup` too, so the change don't wait for `blur` on the `input` fields.

```
$("table").on("change keyup", "tr input", function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest("tr");

    var hrs1  = parseFloat($('[id$=_weekday_hrs]', parent).val())  || 0;
    var hrs2  = parseFloat($('[id$=_weekend_hrs]', parent).val())  || 0;
    var hrs3  = parseFloat($('[id$=_cash_hrs]', parent).val())     || 0;
    var rate1 = parseFloat($('[id$=_weekday_rate]', parent).val()) || 0;
    var rate2 = parseFloat($('[id$=_weekend_rate]', parent).val()) || 0;
    var rate3 = parseFloat($('[id$=_cash_rate]', parent).val())    || 0;

    $('[id$=total_hrs]', parent).val(hrs1 + hrs2 + hrs3);
    $('[id$=_total_salary]', parent).val(hrs1*rate1 + hrs2*rate2 + hrs3*rate3);
});
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/xLLjoego/17/)**

Answer (score -1):

Use the `keyup` event and add a 'input-row' class to each row.

Add the input-row class to all the rows with input boxes:

```
 <tr class="input-row" id="2">
```

When a change is made, you can loop through the rows and calculate the totals:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
    // Get the input rows
    var rows = $('.input-row');
  // Loop through rows
  rows.each(function() {
    // Use the row id to refer to the table input boxes
    var i = $(this).attr('id');

    // Concact each input elements id with the id of the row
    var hrs1 = parseFloat($('#emp'+i+'_weekday_hrs').val()) || 0;
    var hrs2 = parseFloat($('#emp'+i+'_weekend_hrs').val()) || 0;
    var hrs3 = parseFloat($('#emp'+i+'_cash_hrs').val()) || 0;

    var rate1 = parseFloat($('#emp'+i+'_weekday_rate').val()) || 0;
    var rate2 = parseFloat($('#emp'+i+'_weekend_rate').val()) || 0;
    var rate3 = parseFloat($('#emp'+i+'_cash_rate').val()) || 0;

    var totalHrs = hrs1 + hrs2 + hrs3;
    var totalSalary = hrs1*rate1 + hrs2*rate2 + hrs3*rate3

    $('#emp'+i+'_total_hrs').val(totalHrs);
    $('#emp'+i+'_total_salary').val(totalSalary);
  });
})
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/da27zbo2/).

Comment: This is pretty bad and slow, because on an `input` change not even the single row, no, **all** rows will be caluclated again! So you look for every change and recalculate anything. That is not needed and hella slow on more rows too. And beside this you would not need an `id` on the `tr`. You could just use `var i = $(this).index();`.